# what actions can I perform on a Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States   Romania 15
United States   Croatia 1
United States   Ireland 344
```

I converted the above into a `DataFrame`

```
val flightData2015 = spark
.read
.option("inferSchema", "true")//infers the input schema automatically from data
.option("header", "true")//uses the first line as names of columns.
.csv("/data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv");
```

I can get only one column from the `DataFrame` using the `col` function

```
scala> data.col("count");
res70: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = count
```

But I notice that no actions are listed for Column. Are there any actions I can do on a `Column`, eg `max`, `show` etc.

I tried to run `max` function on the `count` column but I still don't see any result.

```
scala> max(dataDS.col("count"));
res78: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = max(count)
```

How do I perform an action on a `Column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No action whatsoever. Column is not a distributed data structure and is not bound to a particular data.

Instead columns are expression which are to be evaluated in specific context of a `Dataset`, like `select`, `filter` or `agg`.

Comment: Thanks. I particularly liked the way you explained the context bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could just [look at the ScalaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Also in the [SparkSQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations), those `$"name"` things are `Column` objects.

So, you could do `flightData2015.select($"count" > 1).show()`, and you would get only two rows.

If you want to find the max of one, then you need to select it from the DataFrame in a different way

Something like this

```
// TODO: import sql functions

flightData2015.select(max($"count"))
```